# How do you read a stream in a middleware and still be streamable in next middleware

Tags: node.js, express, stream, middleware

I'm using a proxy middleware to forward multipart data to a different endpoint. I would like to get some information from the stream using previous middleware, and still have the stream readable for the proxy middleware that follows. Is there stream pattern that allows me to do this?

```
function preMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  req.rawBody = '';

  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    req.rawBody += chunk;
  });

  req.on('end', () => {
    next();
  })
}

function proxyMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.rawBody)
  console.log(req.readable) // false
}

app.use('/cfs', preMiddleware, proxyMiddleware)
```

I want to access the `name` value of `<input name="fee" type='file' />` before sending the streamed data to the external endpoint. I think I need to do this because the endpoint parses `fee` into the final url, and I would like to have a handle for doing some post processing. I'm open to alternative patterns to resolve this.

Comment: I don't think you can "unread" a stream.  You could put the data in another stream and let downstream middleware access it from a different stream, though at that point, you may as well just let the downstream middleware access the parsed data.

Comment: It might also help if you told us the real problem you're trying to solve as there may be other approaches.

Comment: Adding on to @jfriend00's comment, a likely alternative would be a [3xx response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx).

Comment: @jfriend00, I've update my post. Thanks. Please comment on anything not clear.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any mechanism for peeking into a stream without actually permanently removing data from the stream or any mechanism for "unreading" data from a stream to put it back into the stream.

As such, I can think of a few possible ideas:

1. Read the data you want from the stream and then send the data to the final endpoint manually (not using your proxy code that expects the readable stream).
2. Read the stream, get the data you want out if it, then create a new readable stream, put the data you read into that readable stream and pass that readable stream onto the proxy.  Exactly how to pass it only the proxy will need some looking into the proxy code.  You might have to make a new `req` object that is the new stream.
3. Create a stream transform that lets you read the stream (potentially even modifying it) while creating a new stream that can be fed to the proxy.
4. Register your own `data` event handler, then pause the stream (registering a data even automatically triggers the stream to flow and you don't want it to flow yet), then call `next()` right away.  I think this will allow you to "see" a copy of all the data as it goes by when the proxy middleware reads the stream as there will just be multiple `data` event handlers, one for your middleware and one for the proxy middleware.  This is a theoretical idea - I haven't yet tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to be able to send a single stream in two different directions, which is not gonna be easy if you try it on your own - luckily I wrote a helpful module back in the day [rereadable-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rereadable-stream)
, that you could use and I'll use [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) for finding the data you're interested in.

I assume your data will be a multipart-boundary:

```
const {StringStream} = require('scramjet');
const {ReReadable} = require("rereadable-stream");

// I will use a single middleware, since express does not allow to pass an altered request object to next()
app.use('/cfs', (req, res, next) => {
    const buffered = req.pipe(new ReReadable());        // rewind file to 
    let file = '';                                                  
    buffered.pipe(new StringStream)                     // pipe to a StringStream
        .lines('\n')                                    // split request by line
        .filter(x => x.startsWith('Content-Disposition: form-data;'))
                                                        // find form-data lines
        .parse(x => x.split(/;\s*/).reduce((a, y) => {  // split values
            const z = y.split(/:\s*/);                  // split value name from value
            a[z[0]] = JSON.parse(z[1]);                 // assign to accumulator (values are quoted)
            return a;
        }, {}))
        .until(x => x.name === 'fee' && (file = x.filename, 1))
                                                        // run the stream until filename is found
        .run()
        .then(() => uploadFileToProxy(file, buffered.rewind(), res, next))
                                                        // upload the file using your method

});
```

You'll probably need to adapt this a little to make it work in real world scenario. Let me know if you get stuck or there's something to fix in the above answer.